# How Make the players waiting

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I wonder How Make the players waiting؟ like candy crush When the player loses all points of Health He must wait some time

How i can do this?

Thanks

Comment: This question is not asnwerable, so provide more information and add some code you have tried to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a date object when the player loses

```
NSDate *stopTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
```

and store that date in NSUserDefaults.  To check if the user has waited long enough, read the date from NSUserDefaults, and compute the delta between the stop time and the current time.  For example, if the user needs to wait 15 minutes, then

```
NSTimeInterval delta = [stopTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
delta = -delta;
if ( delta > 15 * 60 )
    // OK to play
else
    // still waiting
```